# Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content Magento 2

Tags: magento2, command-line

when i try to run `require extention-name` it gives me following error, i tried many possibilities but it not worked. any advice highly appriciated
i'm using cpanel, centOS 6. and trying to install extention on magento 2.1

```
[muzikhausberlin@vps707732 public_html]$ composer require stripe/stripe-payments
Using version ^1.1 for stripe/stripe-payments
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - zendframework/zend-soap 2.7.0 requires ext-soap * -> the requested PHP extension soap is missing from your system.
    - zendframework/zend-soap 2.7.0 requires ext-soap * -> the requested PHP extension soap is missing from your system.
    - zendframework/zend-soap 2.7.0 requires ext-soap * -> the requested PHP extension soap is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for zendframework/zend-soap (locked at 2.7.0) -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-soap[2.7.0].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-bcmath.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-curl.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-dom.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-gd.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-imap.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-intl.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-json.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-mcrypt.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-mysqlnd.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-pdo.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-phar.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-posix.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-sqlite3.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-xml.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-xsl.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-zip.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/30-mysqli.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/30-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/30-pdo_sqlite.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/30-wddx.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/30-xmlreader.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/zzzzzzz-pecl.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
[
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See if you can find easy apache option on cpanel. You are then looking to modify current selected package combination. You are looking to install the php 7.1 soap extension.  That's about as much advice as I can give you. Exact steps differ between versions.

If you are unsure maybe you can raise a ticket with your hosts and they will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

this is due to miscommunications in auto load files and cache to make things ready you have to dump and auto load files 
commands are `composer dump-autoload -o`
  after that `php artisan config:clear`